# How to select which solution to "run" in multi-solution project

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I am an electronic engineer with limited experience in Visual Studio. I have created a project with 2 solutions. The idea is that the 2nd project will allow to me do some tests more easily.

Now when I click on "build" or "start debuging" or "start without debugging", how do I choose which project should be is targetted by the tool?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project in the Solution Explorer pane, and select `Set as Startup Project`.